# How do I manually upgrade a software package from a Github page?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, macos-mojave, react-native-debugger

I want to upgrade [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases) from version 0.10.0 to version 0.10.2, but clicking to upgrade when the program itself prompts me isn't working because (as they indicate on their page), there's a bug that prevents this upgrade. People have suggested "manually" upgrading or using `brew cask reinstall react-native-debugger`. The latter doesn't work, so I was wondering how you go about manually upgrading a package like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the release page https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases/tag/v0.10.2 and download the appropriate .dmg file (for MacOS) from there. Afterwards you can just install it like any regular .dmg.